# Field of all algebraic reals over $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinite degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I am trying to show that field of all algebraic reals over $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinite degree.
I guess that $$1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[4]{2}, ...$$

are lineary independent but can't prove it.

Comment: The correct term in English is infinite degree, not infinite order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps simpler:

$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]2):\Bbb Q]=n$$

Comment: Why $\sqrt[n]{2}$ cant be the root of polynomial with degree less then $n$?

Comment: @Ashot, because $\;x^n-2\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ is irreducible $\;\forall\,2\le n\in\Bbb N\;$ , say by Eisenstein's Criterion.