# Is $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt[q]3]:\Bbb Q]=pq$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I came across a statement as follows:

> Given any positive integer $n$, there exists a field extension of $\Bbb Q$ of degree $n$

I know $[\Bbb Q:\Bbb Q]=1$,

$[\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]:\Bbb Q]=2$,

$[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]2]:\Bbb Q]=3$,

$[\Bbb Q[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]:\Bbb Q]=4, [\Bbb Q[\sqrt[4]2]:\Bbb Q]=4$

and $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5...]:\Bbb Q]=\infty$.

> Is $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt[q]3]:\Bbb Q]=pq$ (2,3 are randomly chosen primes; and $p$ and $q$ are primes)? Also is it valid for $p=q$?

Is it an established result? If they are not true, can someone provide a simple counter example?

My aim is to have a set of examples for field extension ready given any dimension $n$.

Edit: just found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/659526/45937), clarifying $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[n]2]:\Bbb Q]=n$, $\forall n\in\Bbb N$; hence edited it out of question.

Comment: You mean $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt[q]3]:\Bbb Q]=pq$, with $3$, not $2$? That is correct.

Comment: To summative the comments and your edits: what exactly is your question now ? You could also consider cyclotomic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for $n\ge 1$, and look at their degrees.

Comment: @orangeskid, yes, I put 2 and 3 to make sure both roots doesn't have same prime.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, "certainly not"? I pointed that in light of $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt3,\sqrt2]:\Bbb Q]=4$.

Comment: @Jesse: sorry, I was looking at the title, not the body. In light of the body, the title has a typo in it.

Comment: @Qiaochu, fixed!

Comment: @DietrichBurde, question is very much clear and still unanswered: Is $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt[q]3]:\Bbb Q]=pq$? There was a typo in title; fixed now.

Comment: @Jesse: I think the downvotes came from the typo in the title. In any case, yes, this is true, but it's a bit annoying to prove (I can't think of a really short argument off the top of my head).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, so it is true! An answer with that information and may be a general outline of proof or list of concepts to be used to prove will do, I will dig into it! I also have Herstein's Topics in Algebra, if it has a proof (Quick look into the book didn't help)!

Comment: @barto, from what you pointed out: What happens for $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt[q]2]:\Bbb Q]$? (I know if $q=p^n$, but they are *primes* here.)

Comment: @JessePFrancis $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt[q]2]:\Bbb Q]=\mbox{lcm}(p,q)$ for any $p,q$; indeed for appropriate $a,b$ we have ${\sqrt[p]2}^a{\sqrt[q]2}^b=\sqrt[\text{lcm}(p,q)]2$.

Comment: @barto Thanks! That came as a bonus! :D And in case of primes, $p\ne q$ it is $pq$!